# TestContainers.CosmosDB always gets stuck whenever making any CosmosClient API call

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, testcontainers

I am setting-up TestContainers.CosmosDB for my integration tests. Below is the code I used for running the CosmosDB emulator via docker image.

```
var cosmosDb = new CosmosDbBuilder()
  .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest")
  .Build();
await cosmosDb.StartAsync();
```

Next is the code block I am using to connect to the running instance. But the call to create the database never returns - last line. While running the code, I can browse the CosmosDB explorer and see that the DB instance has spun-up locally but I am not able to interact with it via CosmosClient. How can I use CosmosClient to interact with the TestContainer instance ? I am running Linux containers on Windows machine.
I have published this code here - https://github.com/riteshksriv/ConsoleAppCosmosDB

```
var clientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
{
  ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
  HttpClientFactory = () =>
  {
    HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
      ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
    };
    return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
  }
};
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString, clientOptions);
var dbResponse = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("MyDatabase");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the implementation of the Cosmos DB client. I reviewed the history but could not quickly find all the details.

The Testcontainers for .NET Cosmos DB Emulator module includes a preconfigured [HTTP client](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/62975bc135e0308a88ffbed84aad89fe9f5f1c3e/src/Testcontainers.CosmosDb/CosmosDbContainer.cs#L37). This client [rewrites](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/62975bc135e0308a88ffbed84aad89fe9f5f1c3e/src/Testcontainers.CosmosDb/CosmosDbContainer.cs#L61-L65) the requests to the currently running Cosmos DB Emulator instance. To establish a connection, you will need to either configure the HTTP client yourself or use the [provided module's client](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/62975bc135e0308a88ffbed84aad89fe9f5f1c3e/tests/Testcontainers.CosmosDb.Tests/CosmosDbContainerTest.cs#L17-L36):

```cs
using var httpClient = _cosmosDbContainer.HttpClient;

var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions();
cosmosClientOptions.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway;
cosmosClientOptions.HttpClientFactory = () => httpClient;

using var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(_cosmosDbContainer.GetConnectionString(), cosmosClientOptions);
```

Just an FYI: There is no need to fall back to HTTP. To support HTTPS, we can extract the certificate from the container and configure the HTTP client accordingly. However, this feature has not yet been implemented in the Testcontainers for .NET Cosmos DB Emulator module.

Comment: Just one comment, might want to remove the `using`  on the `httpClient` variable? Otherwise it might dispose an object it really is not owning (the TestContainer owns it?)

Comment: Good point, but I suppose in this case it is ok. The property delegates and creates new HTTP client instances. I believe that in this case, the test serves as the actual owner of the created HTTP instance. However, if there are any disadvantages or aspects I might have overlooked, I am genuinely curious and willing to address them within the module/answer.

Comment: Makes sense. My comment was more around, if the user disposes the HttpClient (let's say they call this code from within a Function) and then attempt to use the _cosmosDbContainer afterwards, they might encounter the HttpClient disposed

Answer (score 2):

High chances the problem is the SDK is unable to establish an HTTP connection to the emulator.

The SDK in an attempt to recover, keeps retrying up to [120](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/a0f1c30521024791aaf93aa3a07aba77c2f8b1bd/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/ClientRetryPolicy.cs#L24) times in these cases.

The retries can be stopped though, if you pass a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout?tabs=cpu-new#cancellationtoken) on the operation.

For example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

... other code...

var dbResponse = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("MyDatabase", cancellation.Token);
```

If this throws an `OperationCanceledException` that means the problem is the HTTP endpoint of the emulator is not reachable and you need to verify the network configuration between the machine running the SDK code and the machine/instance/docker image running the emulator to make sure it is exposing the emulator endpoint publicly.

Comment: Investigated some more - The SDK is trying to connect to https://172.17.0.3:8081 endpoint for DB calls. The emulator is sending below as the read endpoint somehow. It should send localhost:port for it. Not sure why the other endpoint it is sending
    `"readableLocations": [
        {
            "name": "South Central US",
            "databaseAccountEndpoint": "https://172.17.0.3:8081/"
        }`

Comment: The Emulator root URL is sending the following json (https://localhost:58763/)
`{
"readableLocations": [
        {
            "name": "South Central US",
            "databaseAccountEndpoint": "https://172.17.0.3:8081/"
        }
    ],
...
}`

Comment: At this point this issue is escaping the realm of programming I think and rather is going into the specific Cosmos DB Emulator configuration. Maybe this is a configuration that should be done on Testcontainers, like `AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE` and exposing port `8081`? See https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/issues/421#issuecomment-1055588867

Comment: Perhaps the module [configuration](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/e9b48db73bc7798ffbca859517453b5607d044ba/src/Testcontainers.CosmosDb/CosmosDbContainer.cs#L37-L66) will help. It configures the HTTP client in this manner. Have you tried the [module's client](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/e9b48db73bc7798ffbca859517453b5607d044ba/tests/Testcontainers.CosmosDb.Tests/CosmosDbContainerTest.cs#L22-L26)?

Comment: Using the module's client, I am able to connect with the DB. Thanks @AndreHofmeister
This option(AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE ) was updating the endpoint to localhost but connecting to the DB was still not working.

Comment: @AndreHofmeister If you could put your comment as answer, I will accept that and it might help other people later